# on() jQuery not working on children of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, children

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="subcat" class="subcat input1"/>
<div class="input dispsubcat" id="dispsubcat">
    <div class="sub"> abc</div>
    <div class="sub"> xyz</div>
</div
```

jQuery code:

```
$(".input").children("div").on("click",function(){  //does not work
    console.log("hello"); 
})

$(".sub").on("click",function(){ //also does not work
    console.log("hi");
})
```

The following code works which is not what I want:

```
$(".input").on("click",function(){ console.log("ab");})
```

Comment: works fine => http://jsfiddle.net/20gu1a4c/

Comment: Are those `divs` added dynamically?

Comment: this `$(".sub").on("click"..` should work as it is

Comment: Is your HTML code correct ? because i dont think that your `div` should be inside `input` tag ?

Comment: yes i added them dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming those `div` elements are added dynamically, you'll need to delegate the `click` event to your `div` elements by passing in your `"div"` selector as the second argument within jQuery's `on()` method:

```
$(".input").on("click", "div", function() {
    ...
});
```

From [jQuery's `on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

wrap up your code when DOM is ready with jquery **ready** api

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".input").children("div").on("click",function(){  //does not work

    console.log("helo");

})

$(".sub").on("click",function(){ //also does not work
   console.log("hi");
})

});
```

Comment: check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsr2sh52/) all events are working fine.

Comment: i added those children dynamically, that's why it didn't work